# Se puede extraer el .thumbnail de cualquier archivo en el sistema

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

En un post encontré algo relacionado con la extracción de `thumbnail` de archivos `.exe`, lamentablemente no pude probarla debido a que el código se encuentra incompleto y con librerías antiguas.

Después de un rato de investigación logre actualizar los métodos de los que hace uso el script, pero aun me arroja un error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\f.py", line 40, in <module>
    funcion('C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/f.py')
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\f.py", line 16, in funcion
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Y no puedo hacerlo funcionar, espero puedan ayudarme dejo el codigo aqui abajo:

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import os
def funcion(path):

    tempDirectory = os.getenv("temp")
    ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)

    dst = StringIO()

    large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(path,0)
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

    #creating a destination memory DC
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle( win32gui.GetDC(0) )
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ico_x, ico_x)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

    hdc.SelectObject( hbmp )

    #draw a icon in it
    hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), large[0] )
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(large[0])

    #convert picture
    hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")

    im = Image.open(tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")
    im.save(dst, "JPEG")

    dst.seek(0)

    os.remove(tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")
    return dst.read()
funcion('C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/f.py')
```

**Actualizacion 20/11/19**

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import os
def funcion(path):

    tempDirectory = os.getenv("temp")
    ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)

    dst = StringIO()

    large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(path,0)
    #win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

    #creating a destination memory DC
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle( win32gui.GetDC(0) )
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ico_x, ico_x)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

    hdc.SelectObject( hbmp )

    #draw a icon in it
    #hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), large[0] )
    #win32gui.DestroyIcon(large[0])

    #convert picture
    hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")

    im = Image.open(tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")
    im.save("sd", "JPEG")

    dst.seek(0)

    os.remove(tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")
    return dst.read()
funcion('C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/f.py')
```